# Optimize settings in VLC player for precisely seeking dedicated timestamps

Tags: vlc-media-player

I use VLC player (version 3.0.20 Vetinari, apple silicon) to transcribe videos and therefore I often have to jump to precise timestamps. But unfortunately, jumping on the timeline results in a mess with some media files in mpeg2 format: for example, when playhead is at 1:00 and I press the left arrow key to jump some seconds back, the video gets played from 1:23.
I searched the internet and found that [disabling *fast seek*](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=157290#post_content527871) my help, but I couldn't find the setting in VLC settings.

Any help in this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In VLC you can go to **Tools->Preferences** (or Ctrl+P)

then select **All settings** and enter in search field "fast seek", click on **Input/Codecs** and found **Fast seek**

[image: Fast seek option]